# How to find a good HOA Lawyer to deal with confrontational HOA

Tags: real-estate, legal-research, hoa, real-property

Suppose that a person's current HOA is very aggressive with increases, fines and attorney fees that tends to silence community members rather than empowering them.

Suppose that the management contracted by the HOA Board of Directors uses the "Bylaws" and other legal jargon to their advantage. The management claims that fees and assessments charged will improve the value of the property, but this is arguably incorrect. The assessments seem exorbitant. Improvement work is not getting done timely or efficiently. At the same time they enforce assessments aggressively.

Suppose that that the person is looking for an HOA lawyer but is not clear how to choose the right one. Suppose the person  doesn't want a lawyer who is just looking to litigate as litigating with an HOA only adds to the trouble as it just adds to the maintenance costs of the community. Instead, the desire is for someone who will try to understand why the HOA and the community has become dysfunctional and focus attention towards the root cause of the problem. The person also wants the management to stop harassing owners with threats of fees, fines and liens for every increase they make. How can such a person find a lawyer appropriate to such a situation?

EDIT:
One helpful piece of information to help get started is stating services that are relevant for this type of case: E.g., Attorneys state their services such as Traffic, Litigation, etc. What services should the person look for relevant to HOAs to see if a lawyer qualifies? Taking it a bit further, what additional attributes should such a person  look for to make sure the lawyer is a proper fit for the situation at hand? I know these are tough questions but also ones that are the most relevant to anyone starting off.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as it isn't an educational question about the law

Comment: @Rick https://law.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic says that "Dealing with legal professionals" is specifically on-topic, and I think that covers this question. Thus I think it should not be closed. Some of the background detail could and probably should be edited out, however.

Comment: @DavidSiegel - Dealing with legal professionals is not, in my opinion, the same as seeking advice on "how to find a good one"

Comment: I could edit it, just tell me what parts are unnecessary. But I do think there is a lack of information out there for people on how to interview and select a legal professional for specific categorical topics or generally which is in my opinion is in the scope of dealing with "legal professionals (plural)".

Comment: I also vote that keeping some of the background as helpful to the question as I feel that I'm not the only homeowner that has had to deal with difficult situations with HOAs and this specific question can and will most likely help educate future homeowners on finding support from qualified legal counsel.

Comment: @LeanMan The details of your disputes with the HOA, or of the things you feel that the HOA has done improperly, are really not relevant to how to find an appropriate lawyer. A general outline of the kinds of issues that will be involved would IMO  be sufficient.

Comment: I am open to editing it, I could probably use some help though.

Comment: @Rick I think that "dealing with legal professionals"should include "how to interview a lawyer" and "how to find a lawyer appropriate to a particular type of case". I think those kinds of questions are educational in the sense this site is for.

Comment: @LeanMan  I would advise removing most of the 2nd paragraph, keeping only a few lines with the general nature of the issues. That should be enough to do as much as we can toward finding an appropriate lawyer for this issue. I could do such an edit if you like, which you could rollback if you disagreed with it. Or you could do it yourself, or wait for others to chime in.

Comment: Whether this is a question about law might be argued. But I see no way in which asking how best to find a lawyer can be called asking for specific legal advice.

Comment: @DavidSiegel I'll defer it to you since questions like these come from a distressed position. Better if the edit comes from someone who is thinking about future readers and SE. Otherwise I can do it in a few hours from now when I have some more time.

Comment: Edit made, see https://law.stackexchange.com/posts/75289/revisions

Comment: I highly disagree with closing this question. It doesn't need to be exactly about a law. It deals with legal professionals as you cannot just get a list of lawyers and expect each one is a fit for your case. You need to know how to ignore ones that might be able to handle the case from the ones that should handle your case and that, imho, is under "dealing with professionals."